# Parallel.foreach kill thread process

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

This is my code :

```
 [ThreadStatic]
private static WebShopEntities _data;

    public static WebShopEntities data
    {
        get
        {
            if (_data == null)
            {
                _data = new WebShopEntities();
            }
            return _data;
        }
    }
Parallel.ForEach(list,item =>
        {

                data.dp_articles.Add(new dp_articles
                {
                    prom_erp_partno = item.prom_erp_partno,
                    prom_mfm_partno = item.prom_mfm_partno,
                    prol_name = item.prol_name,
                    mfm_short_name = item.mfm_short_name,
                    prom_prfm_id = item.prom_prfm_id
                });
            }

            data.SaveChanges();

        });
```

After it's finished its job the Cpu usage is 99% and the threads doesn't kill by the software automatically!
I searched enough but nothing I'm found!
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What is `data`? An EF datacontext?

Comment: Fine, Did you debug your program? Have you used a profiler to see what's burning your cpu?

Comment: Nobody will be able to tell you what's going on with the current level of detail in your question.

Comment: yes its EF datacontex.
the process is IIS that is 99%

Answer (score 3):

You are using your ORM concurrently. This is not supported. You can't stuff arbitrary code into a parallel loop.

Comment: While you're right, that doesn't answer why it should burn cpu after the loop? Though I don't agree with op, It was in the question.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel L2S guarantees nothing in the presence of race conditions. Who knows what internal data structure is corrupted now? An infinite loop is not at all surprising. Data corruption would also be expected.

Comment: May be you're right. Only way to find out the issue is to debug. and obviously to remove concurrency with ORM.

Comment: it's working fine and database is fulled.
my problem is after it's finishing its job, the process doesn't kill !

Comment: @paradise_human if it is working fine why did you ask this question? It is not working fine as it is causing high cpu usage when it should not. Put the creation of your data context inside the parallel loop and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: ok you are right.
i mean database part is workin fine :D
there is no way to solve ?
wait a minute ...

Comment: We told you how to solve it, repeatadly. Are you not understanding what "Put the creation of your data context inside the parallel loop and see if your problem goes away." means?

Comment: @paradise_human I don't think you have yet understood the severity of the problem I told you about. *Anything* can happen due to this bug including "infinite looping".

Comment: i have updated my post with better information.
i used thread statics

Comment: @paradise_human that changes everything! Good to finally get to know this. Pause the debugger. Where does the it stop?

Comment: @usr but it's happend. I don't know why!!

Comment: @paradise_human let me ask the following to make sure you are on track: What are your next steps to resolve the problem?

Comment: @usr actually i parse a file with 46000 rows and its hard to debug but i know every thing is fine with add all the rows but the process doesn't kill after its job

Comment: @usr I want something that can end this infinitive loop.that's it and kill the process

Comment: @paradise_human I have now voted to close the question because you repeatedly and deliberately deny us information to help you. I have also downvoted for your unhelpful behavior otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54878/discussion-between-paradise-human-and-usr).